# Checkboxes in listbox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

In my code I have listbox:

```
<ListBox Name="ToPlayList">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <CheckBox Checked="Song_Checked" Unchecked="Song_Unchecked"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongTitle}"  Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongArtist}" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,7,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongAlbum}" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongDate}" Foreground="White" Margin="7,0,7,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongDuration}" Foreground="White"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

It's filled by:

```
ToPlayList.ItemsSource = ToPlay;
```

Where `ToPlay` is:

```
public List<Song> ToPlay = new List<Song>();
```

Song Model:

```
public class Song
{
    public string SongTitle { get; set; }
    public string SongArtist { get; set; }
    public string SongDate { get; set; }
    public string SongAlbum { get; set; }
    public string SongPath { get; set; }
    public string SongDuration { get; set; }
    public string SongGenre { get; set; }
}
```

I'm finding function, which make `List<Song>` filled by `Song` objects, which are checked in listbox. Maybe it's trivial, but I am helpless. Thanks for reply.

Comment: _"The only time you should use tags in your title is when they are organic to the conversational tone of the title."_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more property to your song class as

```
 public class Song
 {
        public bool IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string SongTitle { get; set; }
        public string SongArtist { get; set; }
        public string SongDate { get; set; }
        public string SongAlbum { get; set; }
        public string SongPath { get; set; }
        public string SongDuration { get; set; }
        public string SongGenre { get; set; }
 }
```

Change ListBox as

```
<ListBox Name="ToPlayList">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>

            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongTitle}"  Foreground="Black"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongArtist}" Foreground="White" Margin="0,0,7,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongAlbum}" Foreground="White"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongDate}" Foreground="White" Margin="7,0,7,0"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding SongDuration}" Foreground="White"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Now on a button click or something

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    var check = ((List<Song>)(ToPlayList.ItemsSource)).Where(x=>x.IsChecked);
 }
```